# Android Studio get value from cursor

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a value from a cursor but I get an error.

I tried both methods but neither are working.

cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pseudo"));

Getting value from cursor
[image]

```
String Pseudo = cursor.getString(2);
```

Comment: If cursor is NULL?

Comment: Did you call cursor.moveToFirst() before getting string?

Comment: It worked, forget to move to the first. thanks